# Create an alias for cleartool in windows

Tags: windows, alias, clearcase

I'm wondering how to create a alias for `cleartool` in windows.
In Linux, its pretty straight forward(alias).

How can I set the alias for `cleartool` in Windows?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "alias"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [doskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY):

```
doskey ct=cleartool $*
```

You can generalize the idea to other ClearCase commands:

```
doskey ct=cleartool $*
doskey mt=multitool $*
doskey credmap="C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\credmap.exe" $*
doskey creds="C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\creds.exe" $*
```

---

Also ([from this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000002919108)):

> To have instances of `cmd.exe` automatically load your doskey aliases: (this might be XP specific)
>
> 1. Create a macro file.  (ex:  `doskey /macros > c:\some\dir\my_macros.txt`)
> 2. Create the following registry entry:

```
    hkey_current_user\software\microsoft\Command Processor
```

> with a value of:

```
    Autorun = %systemroot%\system32\doskey.exe /macrofile=c:\some\dir\my_macros.txt
```